# While printing array list only last value is printed

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist

I am trying to read CSV file that has value in only one column like

```
11111
22222
33333
44444
```

I am able to read the file but when I am  printing the value that only prints the last value, that is 44444. Below is my code, please help me to get all the values in list and print:-

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.lang.reflect.Array;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;

public class ReadCVS {

  public static void main(String[] args) {

    ReadCVS obj = new ReadCVS();
    obj.run();

  }

  @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
public void run() {

    String csvFile = "/C:/Users/SONY/Desktop/Book1.csv";
    BufferedReader br = null;
    String line = "";
    String cvsSplitBy = ",";
    List<String[]> list=new ArrayList<String[]>();

    try {

        br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(csvFile));
        String[] country = null ;
        while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {

            country= line.split(cvsSplitBy);

            list.add(country);
            System.out.println(Arrays.toString(country));
        }

        for(int i = 0; i < country.length; i++) {
            System.out.println(Arrays.toString(country));             
        }


    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        if (br != null) {
            try {
                br.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }

    System.out.println("Done");
  }

}
```

Comment: You should be printing out `list`

Comment: If the file only has one value in each line, why are you splitting the line at all?

Comment: Thanks Sam,But when i printing list it's give me like Ljava.lang.String;@6e1408, [Ljava.lang.String;@e53108, [Ljava.lang.String;@f62373,Please help

Comment: After changing my code  List<String[]> list=new ArrayList<String[]>(); to  List<String> list=new ArrayList<String>(); i am able to print the values in String format.Thanks RealSkeptic for ponting my error i remove that split line from my code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you are printing `country` in the second `for loop` which contains that value of the last column which in your case is `44444`

Try something like this.

```
List<String[]> list = new ArrayList();
try {
    list.add(new String[]{"a","b"});
    list.add(new String[]{"c","d"});
    
    for (String[] str: list) {
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(str));
    }
} catch (Exception e) {}
```

Output:

> [a, b]
>
> [c, d]

It's a generic example trying to simulate yours. Make changes as per your requirements. And never leave **exceptions uncaught** like I did in my example above.